# laravel orm reach one model via multiple pivot tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I'm fairly new in Laravel and I've come to a problem. I'll just go straight to it:
So I have theese tables in my database:

```
Instructor (Id,name)
Licence (Id,name)
Discipline (Id,name)
Module (Id,name)
```

Pivot tables:

```
LicenceDiscipline(id, fk_discipline_id, fk_licence_id)
LicenceDisciplineInstructor(id, fk_licence_discipline_id, fk_instructor_id)
LicenceDisciplineInstructorModule(fk_licence_discipline_instructor_id, fk_module_id)
```

Models in laravel:
Instructor, Licence, Discipline, Module.

Instructor can choose a licence (he can have more), and each licence he chooses has one discipline (there are more disciplines to choose from). Now at the discipline the instructor has chosen, he can choose from multiple modules and he can choose 0 or * of them.

So my question is: How would i define a relationship in laravel at model Instructor and put in a function like:

```
public function modules(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Modules');
    }
```

so i can get all of the instructors modules?
Keep in mind that I have to go from Instructor through licenceDisciplineInstructor, check 'that' ID in LicenceDisciplineInstructorModule and get all the modules that the instructor has.